# How do I set the number of bytes read by ifstream get()?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I'm trying to parse MIDI, which needs to be read 8 bits (one byte) at a time. On my system(*), `ifs.get()` seems to be grabbing 32 bits at a time.

```
std::ifstream ifs;
ifs.open(FileName, std::fstream::in | std::ios::binary);

std::cout << "size:: " << sizeof(ifs.get()) <<std::endl; // returns 4
```

Is it possible to simply specify the number of bytes per read so `ifs.get()` gets only one byte (8 bits) at a time?

The reason why I believe `ifs.get()` is returning more than 8 bits is because:

```
uint16_t nReadByte = 0;
nReadByte = ifs.get();
std::cout << std::hex << nReadByte <<std::endl;
```

Produces results like:

```
3e,28,0,42,28,0,3b,28
```

But if I set the variable size to 8 bits I get bizarre characters:

```
uint8_t nReadByte = 0;
nReadByte = ifs.get();            
std::cout << std::hex << nReadByte <<std::endl;
```

`@,,,,.,4,p,s,2,`. (These don't seem to be rendering here correctly, but sometimes they look like the letters `ETX` and `CAN` in a single glyph.

Comment: You are using `sizeof` incorrectly.

Comment: What is the correct way to determine how many bytes are being returned by `ifs.get()`?

Answer (score 4):

> On my system(*), `ifs.get()` seems to be grabbing 32 bits at a time.

Your example proving this is incorrect. First of all, the `ifs.get()` inside `sizeof` won't even get evaluated, because expressions in `sizeof` don't get evaluated. Second of all, `std::ifstream` is an alias for `std::basic_ifstream<char>`, and [`ifs.get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) taking no parameters will indeed return one character of the `std::basic_ifstream`'s character type. Since this is `char` in your case, if `CHAR_BIT` (defined in `<climits>`) is defined as 8 on your system then it will indeed read 8 bits at a time.

The reason `sizeof(ifs.get())` is 4 is because `ifs.get()`'s return value is `std::ifstream::traits_type::int_type` which is `int` (the reason the return value is not `char` is because it may need to return `std::ifstream::traits_type::eof()` as well which may not fit in `char`). And on your system, `sizeof (int)` is 4.

The reason output looks different for `uint16_t` and `uint8_t` seems to be that for `uint16_t` it's actually printing the bytes as hex whereas for `uint8_t` it seems to be printing as characters (`uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char` and `ostream`s overload `operator<<(unsigned char)` to print characters), which is why some are not showing and the output generally looks different.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I set the number of bytes read by ifstream get()?

The second parameter is the number of bytes to read, if you give a buffer as the first targument.

> On my system(*), ifs.get() seems to be grabbing 32 bits at a time.

You're mistaken. The nullary overload reads exactly one byte. The return type is `int` so that it can represent, besides all possible values of a `char`, also EOF (End Of File) which is a special value outside the range of `char` that is returned if the stream has reached the end.

> ```
> uint16_t nReadByte = 0;
> nReadByte = ifs.get();
> std::cout << std::hex << nReadByte <<std::endl;
> ```

`uint16_t`  is an alias of `unsigned short` or `unsigned int` neither of which are character types. When you insert a non-character integer into a character stream, it will be represented as a number corresponding to its numeric value; in this case modified by the `std::hex` manipulator.

> But if I set the variable size to 8 bits I get bizarre characters:
>
> ```
> uint8_t nReadByte = 0;
> nReadByte = ifs.get();            
> std::cout << std::hex << nReadByte <<std::endl;
> ```

`uint8_t`  is an alias of `unsigned char` which is a character type. When you insert a character into a character stream, it will not be represented by a number corresponding to its numeric value. Instead, it will  be represented by a symbol corresponding to the value in the current character encoding. Some values aren't visible symbols, but rather control characters that affect how a terminal behaves for example.

If you want to stream the numeric value of a character object, then you must convert to another integer type such as `unsigned int`.

> (These don't seem to be rendering here correctly

When used in contexts where they aren't meaningful, control characters may helpfully be shown with a visible symbol, but not all fonts have such place-holders and websites often remove them when sainiting user input.

Answer (score 1):

it seemes ifstream::read is better.

from https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/

```
istream& read (char* s, streamsize n);
```

Read block of data

Extracts n characters from the stream and stores them in the array pointed to by s.